# Assigning permission to role while seeding - Entrust

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding, entrust, eloquent-relationship

Laravel 5.6.3
Entrust: 1.9

I am trying to seed only one row with this Seeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\models\Permission;
use App\models\Role;

class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       $role =  Role::create([
            'name' => 'super-admin',
            'display_name' => 'Super Admin',
            'description' => 'This will be one permission, that can not be assigned or created.'
        ]);

        $permission = Permission::first()->where('name', 'super-admin')->first();
        $role->attachPermission($permission);
    }
}
```

And model

```
<?php

namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

use App\models\Permission;
use App\User;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to seed, I am getting this error.

```
D:\work\www\myapp>php artisan db:seed --class=PermissionSeeder

D:\work\www\myapp>php artisan db:seed --class=RoleSeeder

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Permission' not found

  at D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php:656
    652|      * @return mixed
    653|      */
    654|     protected function newRelatedInstance($class)
    655|     {
  > 656|         return tap(new $class, function ($instance) {
    657|             if (! $instance->getConnectionName()) {
    658|                 $instance->setConnection($this->connection);
    659|             }
    660|         });

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newRelatedInstance("App\Permission")
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php:418

  2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::belongsToMany("App\Permission", "permission_role", "role_id", "permission_id")
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\zizaco\entrust\src\Entrust\Traits\EntrustRoleTrait.php:80

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.


Using -v

D:\work\www\myapp>php artisan db:seed --class=RoleSeeder -v

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Permission' not found

  at D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php:656
    652|      * @return mixed
    653|      */
    654|     protected function newRelatedInstance($class)
    655|     {
  > 656|         return tap(new $class, function ($instance) {
    657|             if (! $instance->getConnectionName()) {
    658|                 $instance->setConnection($this->connection);
    659|             }
    660|         });

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newRelatedInstance("App\Permission")
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php:418

  2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::belongsToMany("App\Permission", "permission_role", "role_id", "permission_id")
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\zizaco\entrust\src\Entrust\Traits\EntrustRoleTrait.php:80

  3   Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole::perms()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\zizaco\entrust\src\Entrust\Traits\EntrustRoleTrait.php:177

  4   Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole::attachPermission()
      D:\work\www\myapp\database\seeds\RoleSeeder.php:23

  5   RoleSeeder::run()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29

  6   call_user_func_array([])
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29

  7   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:87

  8   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:31

  9   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:564

  10  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Seeder.php:122

  11  Illuminate\Database\Seeder::__invoke()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php:63

  12  Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand::Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\{closure}()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes.php:122

  13  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguarded(Object(Closure))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php:64

  14  Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand::handle()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29

  15  call_user_func_array([])
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:29

  16  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:87

  17  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:31

  18  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:564

  19  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:179

  20  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:251

  21  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:166

  22  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:886

  23  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:262

  24  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:145

  25  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:89

  26  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      D:\work\www\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:122

  27  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      D:\work\www\myapp\artisan:37

D:\work\www\myapp>
```

**Update**

I tried it on tinker

```
>>> $permission = App\models\Permission::first();
=> App\models\Permission {#2923
     id: 1,
     name: "super-admin",
     display_name: "Super Admin",
     description: "This will be one permission, that can not be assigned or created.",
     created_at: "2018-08-31 05:01:08",
     updated_at: "2018-08-31 05:01:08",
   }
>>> $role = App\models\Role::first();
=> App\models\Role {#2925
     id: 1,
     name: "super-admin",
     display_name: "Super Admin",
     description: "This will be one permission, that can not be assigned or modified.",
     created_at: "2018-08-31 05:01:10",
     updated_at: "2018-08-31 05:01:10",
   }
>>> $role->attachPermission($permission);
PHP Error:  Class 'App/Permission' not found in D:/work/www/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php on line 656
>>>
```

What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: you want separate model for Role and Permission table?

Comment: Somewhere you have `App\Permission`; instead of `use App\models\Permission;`

Comment: @JinalSomaiya as they are separate tables.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I thought same and looked into every file, but I have used correct in every file . `App\models\Permission;`

Comment: how do you define relationships in laravel, using annotations? could it be there?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I searched in my visual code and there is no use of `App\Permission`.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I have posted the Role model, check it that is how we define relationship.

Comment: Role is in the namespace App\models; So you can remove the use statement for Permission. Try that first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179105/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-delboy1978uk).

Comment: chat is blocked

Comment: @delboy1978uk Actually I was using use Permission; instead of use App\models\Permission;but I was getting same problem, so tried giving full name space.

Comment: remove the use statement completely for permission in the role class

Comment: @delboy1978uk Getting same error.

Comment: can you use -v to get the full stack trace?

Comment: @delboy1978uk check this https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/1fb54ca44f8c126d9a92e6d964911fb4

Comment: unbelievably, gists are blocked on this network :-(

Comment: @delboy1978uk wait a minute, I will add it somewhere else and post the link.

Comment: @delboy1978uk check this https://pastebin.com/CLWzqL2s

Comment: can't you put it in your question? 'The proxies security policy blocked your request '

Comment: @delboy1978uk check it now.

Comment: @delboy1978uk reload the question, I have added it to my question.

Comment: looks like the error occurs on this line `$permission = Permission::first()->where('name', 'super-admin')->first();`

Comment: @delboy1978uk that is giving correct result,

Comment: @delboy1978uk I tried it in tinker before using it on code.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu did you change the `permission` model namespace in `config/entrust.php`, it should be 'permission' => `App\models\Permission` default it is set to `App\Permission`

Comment: @rkj you are correct, that was the problem.Please post it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At bottom of https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust repo it says

> If your app uses a custom namespace then you'll need to tell entrust
>   where your permission and role models are, you can do this by editing
>   the config file in `config/entrust.php`

So in your case you have to change the permission model namespace to `App\models\Permission` default it is set to `App\Permission`

So edit `config/entrust.php` file and change `permission`

```
'permission' => 'App\models\Permission'
```

and

```
'role' => 'App\models\Role'
```